# Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 299, 299, 3)) at layer "input_1"

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 299, 299, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "input_1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

How can I eliminate the error? I am trying to build inceptionv3 network and call but model is not getting compiled. I believe the input layer is not at all getting inputs but i don't understand why

```
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

import warnings
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Model
from keras import layers
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import AveragePooling2D
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.layers import GlobalMaxPooling2D
from keras.engine.topology import get_source_inputs
from keras.utils.layer_utils import convert_all_kernels_in_model
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
from keras import backend as K
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import decode_predictions
#from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
from keras.preprocessing import image
WEIGHTS_PATH = 'https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.5/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5'
WEIGHTS_PATH_NO_TOP = 'https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.5/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'
def conv2d_bn(x,filters,num_row,num_col,padding='same',strides=(1, 1),name=None):
    if name is not None:
        bn_name = name + '_bn'
        conv_name = name + '_conv'
    else:
        bn_name = None
        conv_name = None
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        bn_axis = 1
    else:
        bn_axis = 3
    x = Conv2D(filters, (num_row, num_col),strides=strides,padding=padding,use_bias=False,name=conv_name)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis=bn_axis, scale=False, name=bn_name)(x)
    x = Activation('relu', name=name)(x)
    return x

def InceptionV3(include_top=True,
                weights='imagenet',
                input_tensor=None,
                input_shape=None,
                pooling=None,
                classes=1000):

    if weights not in {'imagenet', None}:
        raise ValueError('The `weights` argument should be either '
                         '`None` (random initialization) or `imagenet` '
                         '(pre-training on ImageNet).')

    if weights == 'imagenet' and include_top and classes != 1000:
        raise ValueError('If using `weights` as imagenet with `include_top`'
                         ' as true, `classes` should be 1000')

    # Determine proper input shape
    input_shape = (299,299,3)

    if input_tensor is None:
        img_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    else:
        img_input = keras.layers.Input(tensor=input_tensor, shape=input_shape)

    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        channel_axis = 1
    else:
        channel_axis = 3

    x = conv2d_bn(img_input, 32, 3, 3, strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')
    x = conv2d_bn(x, 32, 3, 3, padding='valid')
    x = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 3, 3)
    x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)

    x = conv2d_bn(x, 80, 1, 1, padding='valid')
    x = conv2d_bn(x, 192, 3, 3, padding='valid')
    x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)

    # mixed 0: 35 x 35 x 256, type 1 module
    branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)

    branch5x5 = conv2d_bn(x, 48, 1, 1)
    branch5x5 = conv2d_bn(branch5x5, 64, 5, 5)

    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)
    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)
    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)

    branch_pool = AveragePooling2D((3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
    branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 32, 1, 1)
    x = layers.concatenate(
        [branch1x1, branch5x5, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool],
        axis=channel_axis,
        name='mixed0')

    # mixed 1: 35 x 35 x 288, type 1 module
    branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)

    branch5x5 = conv2d_bn(x, 48, 1, 1)
    branch5x5 = conv2d_bn(branch5x5, 64, 5, 5)

    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)
    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)
    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)

    branch_pool = AveragePooling2D((3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
    branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 64, 1, 1)
    x = layers.concatenate(
        [branch1x1, branch5x5, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool],
        axis=channel_axis,
        name='mixed1')

    # mixed 2: 35 x 35 x 288, type 1 module
    branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)

    branch5x5 = conv2d_bn(x, 48, 1, 1)
    branch5x5 = conv2d_bn(branch5x5, 64, 5, 5)

    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)
    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)
    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)

    branch_pool = AveragePooling2D((3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
    branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 64, 1, 1)
    x = layers.concatenate(
        [branch1x1, branch5x5, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool],
        axis=channel_axis,
        name='mixed2')

    # mixed 3: 17 x 17 x 768,type 2module
    branch3x3 = conv2d_bn(x, 384, 3, 3, strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')

    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)
    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)
    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(
        branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3, strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')

    branch_pool = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)
    x = layers.concatenate(
        [branch3x3, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool], axis=channel_axis, name='mixed3')

    # mixed 4: 17 x 17 x 768,type3 module
    branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 192, 1, 1)

    branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(x, 128, 1, 1)
    branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(branch7x7, 128, 1, 7)
    branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(branch7x7, 192, 7, 1)

    branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 128, 1, 1)
    branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 128, 7, 1)
    branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 128, 1, 7)
    branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 128, 7, 1)
    branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 192, 1, 7)

    branch_pool = AveragePooling2D((3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
    branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 192, 1, 1)
    x = layers.concatenate(
        [branch1x1, branch7x7, branch7x7dbl, branch_pool],
        axis=channel_axis,
        name='mixed4')

    # mixed 5, 6: 17 x 17 x 768,type3 modules
    for i in range(2):
        branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 192, 1, 1)

        branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(x, 160, 1, 1)
        branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(branch7x7, 160, 1, 7)
        branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(branch7x7, 192, 7, 1)

        branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 160, 1, 1)
        branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 160, 7, 1)
        branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 160, 1, 7)
        branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 160, 7, 1)
        branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 192, 1, 7)

        branch_pool = AveragePooling2D(
            (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
        branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 192, 1, 1)
        x = layers.concatenate(
            [branch1x1, branch7x7, branch7x7dbl, branch_pool],
            axis=channel_axis,
            name='mixed' + str(5 + i))

    # mixed 7: 17 x 17 x 768, type 3 module
    branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 192, 1, 1)

    branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(x, 192, 1, 1)
    branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(branch7x7, 192, 1, 7)
    branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(branch7x7, 192, 7, 1)

    branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 192, 1, 1)
    branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 192, 7, 1)
    branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 192, 1, 7)
    branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 192, 7, 1)
    branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 192, 1, 7)

    branch_pool = AveragePooling2D((3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
    branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 192, 1, 1)
    x = layers.concatenate(
        [branch1x1, branch7x7, branch7x7dbl, branch_pool],
        axis=channel_axis,
        name='mixed7')

    # mixed 8: 8 x 8 x 1280, type 4 module
    branch3x3 = conv2d_bn(x, 192, 1, 1)
    branch3x3 = conv2d_bn(branch3x3, 320, 3, 3,
                          strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')

    branch7x7x3 = conv2d_bn(x, 192, 1, 1)
    branch7x7x3 = conv2d_bn(branch7x7x3, 192, 1, 7)
    branch7x7x3 = conv2d_bn(branch7x7x3, 192, 7, 1)
    branch7x7x3 = conv2d_bn(
        branch7x7x3, 192, 3, 3, strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')

    branch_pool = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)
    x = layers.concatenate(
        [branch3x3, branch7x7x3, branch_pool], axis=channel_axis, name='mixed8')

    # mixed 9: 8 x 8 x 2048, type 5 modules
    for i in range(2):
        branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 320, 1, 1)

        branch3x3 = conv2d_bn(x, 384, 1, 1)
        branch3x3_1 = conv2d_bn(branch3x3, 384, 1, 3)
        branch3x3_2 = conv2d_bn(branch3x3, 384, 3, 1)
        branch3x3 = layers.concatenate(
            [branch3x3_1, branch3x3_2], axis=channel_axis, name='mixed9_' + str(i))

        branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 448, 1, 1)
        branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 384, 3, 3)
        branch3x3dbl_1 = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 384, 1, 3)
        branch3x3dbl_2 = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 384, 3, 1)
        branch3x3dbl = layers.concatenate(
            [branch3x3dbl_1, branch3x3dbl_2], axis=channel_axis)

        branch_pool = AveragePooling2D(
            (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
        branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 192, 1, 1)
        x = layers.concatenate(
            [branch1x1, branch3x3, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool],
            axis=channel_axis,
            name='mixed' + str(9 + i))


    x = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)

    # Ensure that the model takes into account
    # any potential predecessors of `input_tensor`.
    if input_tensor is not None:
        inputs = get_source_inputs(input_tensor)
    else:
        img_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
        inputs = img_input
    # Create model.
    model = Model(inputs,x, name='inception_v3')
    '''

    # load weights
    if weights == 'imagenet':
        if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
            if K.backend() == 'tensorflow':
                warnings.warn('You are using the TensorFlow backend, yet you '
                              'are using the Theano '
                              'image data format convention '
                              '(`image_data_format="channels_first"`). '
                              'For best performance, set '
                              '`image_data_format="channels_last"` in '
                              'your Keras config '
                              'at ~/.keras/keras.json.')
        if include_top:
            weights_path = get_file(
                'inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5',
                WEIGHTS_PATH,
                cache_subdir='models',
                md5_hash='9a0d58056eeedaa3f26cb7ebd46da564')
        else:
            weights_path = get_file(
                'inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5',
                WEIGHTS_PATH_NO_TOP,
                cache_subdir='models',
                md5_hash='bcbd6486424b2319ff4ef7d526e38f63')
        model.load_weights(weights_path)
        if K.backend() == 'theano':
            convert_all_kernels_in_model(model)
    '''      

    return model
model = InceptionV3(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',input_shape=(299,299,3))
print(model.summary())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to comment this lines:

```
#     if input_tensor is not None:
#         inputs = get_source_inputs(input_tensor)
#     else:
#         img_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
#         inputs = img_input
```

and create your model in this way:

```
model = Model(img_input, x, name='inception_v3')
```